# Get color of a chart series

Tags: vb.net, charts, colors, get, series

I need to get the color of a series that is set by smart lables, I want to make a cell in a DGV the same color.

```
Dim chtColor(50) As Color

For Each Cur In MCurves
    PTang = EstCurve(Cur, BladeAngle, HRfan)

    Me.ChtCurves.Series.Add(Cur.ToString)
    Me.ChtCurves.Series(Cur.ToString).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline
    Me.ChtCurves.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "#.###"
    chtColor(i) = Me.ChtCurves.Series(Cur.ToString).Color
```

The function `Me.ChtCurves.Series(Cur.ToString).Color` is returning a list of Colors and not the Series color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not explicitly setting a series color and want to retrieve the default assigned color, then you must call [`Chart.ApplyPaletteColors()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.applypalettecolors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Modify your code to call this method after adding the Series to the chart's Series collection

```
Me.ChtCurves.Series.Add(Cur.ToString)
Me.ChtCurves.Series(Cur.ToString).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline
Me.ChtCurves.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "#.###"

Me.ChtCurves.ApplyPaletteColors() ' this will allow you to retrieve the default color

chtColor(i) = Me.ChtCurves.Series(Cur.ToString).Color
```

Comment: Thank you for the help TnTinMin, this works however i will need to take an explicit route as and change in the charts changes the charts colors using Smart Labels. my current code redraws all the curves, I will look at only removing the affected chart, this may retain the other Series colors.

Comment: I set the datagridview to a color and then used Linq to get the colors and set the Series.

           `Dim MCurves = From C As DataGridViewRow In Me.DgvCurves.Rows
                          Where C.Cells("Selected").Value = "True"
                          Select C.Cells("VentiID").Value, C.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor `